# Retrieve Nested XML data in Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, xml, api, nested

Im new to rails and have a rails app calling an api and inserting the XML array data into DB. I am having a problem accessing the nested part of the XML data, the part where it says {Category=}{CategoryDescription = COMEDY} Here is the array. I cant figure out how to store the Category Description = COMEDY in the DB.

```
{"Array"=>{"Artist"=>[{"Category"={"CategoryDescription"=>"COMEDY", "ChildCategoryID"=>"xx"}, "Description"=>"Adam Sandler", "ID"=>"14",}
```

Here is how I accessed and created the Description and ID from the array but cant figure out how to retrieve the nested Category response.

```
doc = response.parsed_response
doc["Array"]["Artist"].each do |category|

performer = Performer.create(  PerformerID:  category['ID'],
                         PerformerName: category['Description'],
```

I tried this to access and store the Nested [Category] in the XML response.

```
doc2["Array"]["Artist"]["Category"].each do |category|

performerCategory = Performer.create(EventID: category['ChildCategoryDescription'],)
```

it says it cant convert string to integer. Anything will help thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to convert `category['ChildCategoryDescription']` to an integer, try `to_i` like this:

```
performerCategory = Performer.create(EventID: category['ChildCategoryDescription'].to_i,)
```